# Switch to next activity after all the text is shown without user having to do anything. After all text has been shown, screen changes automatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So when the user downloads my app I would like the initial activity to be the `FadedTextActivity` where the title of the app appears, and another text, and then I have used `Timer` to make it so that after 9 seconds the Activity automatically moves to the next Activity. The only problem is that now, for example the FadedTextActivity is my launcher Activity and if the user is logged in it skips that Activity, Register, and Login Activities.

The only issue is that even if the user is already logged in the Timer for some reason still goes off even though it didn't even have to go through that activity to launch the app (because the user was already logged in)… Is there a way to make it so the timer only goes off if it's **FadedTextActivity** and if it goes straight to MainActivity then the timer shouldn't refresh the page like it currently does?

**FadingTextActivity**

```
public class FadingTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fading_text);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser != null && mFirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FadingTextActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 9000);

            FadingTextView fadingTextView = findViewById(R.id.fading_tv);
            String[] fadingTv = {"Events", "What's happening in your world today?"};
            fadingTextView.setTexts(fadingTv);
            fadingTextView.setTimeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FadingTextView` doesn't look like android sdk widget , doesn't it provide some kind of listener

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan hey, it's not. I added a dependency to make it work. I just added the xml file so you can see it. Not sure about the listener either. Is there something I can do for example when both words have been shown for a pendingIntent to take me to the next Activity, or I don't know... Something along those lines?

Comment: working on it , i will let you know

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan okay, thanks buddy! Let me know if you think of something!

Comment: was my answer any help?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [source code](https://github.com/rosenpin/fading-text-view/blob/master/fadingtextview/src/main/java/com/tomer/fadingtextview/FadingTextView.java) of i figured out a few ways to know when the all text is shown in the FadingTextView

i turns out they could have easily provide a listener for that but they didn't so we need to do some tricks which are not very good practices and makes the code complex , but if you really want to start and next activity after the text is shown here are my solutions

**solution 1**

As you know can calculate the time it takes to show you all the texts by multiplying the the time you set and number of strings you passed in `setTexts()` you can just check on a background thread if that time has elapsed since the program started, like the following

```
 public class FadingTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private int startTime = System.currentTimeinMillis() 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fading_text);

    FadingTextView fadingTextView = findViewById(R.id.fading_tv);
    String[] fadingTv = {"Events", "What's happening in your world today?"};
    fadingTextView.setTexts(fadingTv);
    fadingTextView.setTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 new TimeChecker().execute(3000);
}
}
```

Create asynktask

```
//create an inner class asynctask to check if the desired time is elapsed
 class TimeChecker extends AsynTask{
 protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + params[0]){}
               // it will continue to iterate whenever this thread get a chance and 
 //only exit if time you passed is over
 }
//below method will be called after above method means after the given time has 
 elapsed
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     // start activity here
 }
}
```

although it is not a very nice and clean solution but we don't have many choices

**solution 2**

there is a protected method in the `FadingTextView` which is continously after `timeout` time you given , so if you create the `FadingTextView` in code you can easily override that method and start your activity when this method is called second time, but this is not also a very good solution

**solution 3**

you can take their [source](https://github.com/rosenpin/fading-text-view/blob/master/fadingtextview/src/main/java/com/tomer/fadingtextview/FadingTextView.java) analyze it and introduce a callback which will let you listen when the all of texts have been rendered once, you will not need any dependency then you can just include the whole source in your project , it is just two classes and a few res files

sorry i know i didn't provide very elegant solutions but we didn't have any other choices at least i couldn't figure out because we can't modify the source of 'FadingEdgeText`and it doesn't look like this class was designed for inheritance also doesn't provide too much to the client so we need these tricks

**have a good day**

Comment: Hey buddy! Thanks for the solutions. I will look into them. I figured out a rather easy way to do it. I updated my code... But I will look at yours just to compare apples to apples. Thanks man!

Comment: @JMB you are welcome , and there is one more , you can create your own FadingTextView by subclassing TextView you can make it show the text only once and also provide a callaback to execute code when the all text is shown, and i am afraid there might not be better solutions , this one is best BTW you will also learn about custom views in the process of doing that

Comment: @JMB you are welcome , and there is one more , you can create your own FadingTextView by subclassing TextView you can make it show the text only once and also provide a callaback to execute code when the all text is shown, and i am afraid there might not be better solutions , this one is best BTW you will also learn about custom views in the process of doing that